# How can I make gdb print unprintable characters of a string in hex instead of octal while preserving the ascii characters in ascii form?

Tags: c, string, debugging, assembly, gdb

Suppose I have a buffer `buf` whose c string representation is

```
 char* buf = "Hello World \x1c"
```

When I print this buf in gdb using the command `p buf`, I get the following

```
 $1 = "Hello World \034"
```

**Is there a print command or a gdb setting that will print the following instead?**

```
$1 = "Hello World \x1c"
```

I have tried various format parameters such as `/c` and  `/x`, but none of them get the effect that I am looking for. I have also played with printf but was unable to achieve the desired effect.

Update: I am using "GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0.1-debian".

Update: 
I have played with x as well.

If I do `x/c` it prints octal and decimal for nonprintable characters, and then prints printable characters with the ascii and decimal.

If I do `x/s` it outputs exactly the same as the p command.

If I do `x/x` it just outputs hex but then we lose the ascii characters for the printable part.

Update: This [reference](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html#Print-Settings), unless incomplete, suggests that what I desire is not available, but can anyone confirm?

Comment: Looks like octal was all the rage back in the day. I asked [a similar question for Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/showing-bytes-as-hexadecimal-escapes-rather-than-octal-escapes) (thanks to one of the people who saw the question, a feature has been added to Emacs), and now running into octal again when reading the source code of TeX and when looking at gdb output. :-) Thanks for this question and answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the absence of an existing solution, I created [this gdb command](https://github.com/hq6/GdbAsciiHexPrint) which prints ascii and hex for strings that have mixed printable ascii and non-printable characters. The source is reproduced below.

```py
    from __future__ import print_function
    
    import gdb
    import string
    class PrettyPrintString (gdb.Command):
        "Command to print strings with a mix of ascii and hex."
    
        def __init__(self):
            super (PrettyPrintString, self).__init__("ascii-print",
                    gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                    gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION, True)
            gdb.execute("alias -a pp = ascii-print", True)
    
        def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
            arg = arg.strip()
            if arg == "":
                print("Argument required (starting display address).")
                return
            startingAddress = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg)
            p = 0
            print('"', end='')
            while startingAddress[p] != ord("\0"):
                charCode = int(startingAddress[p].cast(gdb.lookup_type("char")))
                if chr(charCode) in string.printable:
                    print("%c" % chr(charCode), end='')
                else:
                    print("\\x%x" % charCode, end='')
                p += 1
            print('"')
    
    PrettyPrintString()
```

To use this, one can simply put the `source AsciiPrintCommand.py` and then run the following in gdb. For convenience, one can put put the above source command into their `$HOME/.gdbinit`.

```
ascii-print buf
"Hello World \x1c"
```

Comment: I tried your solution, into a file ~/.gdb-ascii-print.py. Didn't work
source ~/.gdb-ascii-print0.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.gdb-ascii-print0.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "~/.gdb-ascii-print0.py", line 11, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COMPLETE_EXPRESSION'

Comment: [`COMPLETE_EXPRESSION` was added 2013](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/92e32e33f16b40988327df8e8beacf3a8a356916#diff-6eb269e692ab14d02685ebc27583250c9829234c4de6de0b3330cd2edd55f07a), if you don't have it in your very old GDB you can use `gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but when run the command, I get an error saying, `Error occurred in Python: Cannot subscript requested type.` I know it's referring to `startingAddress[p]`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @AndrewLamarra I'm not sure what's changed in gdb in the last 6 years, but if you want to debug, I'd recommend modifying the script to print `startingAddress` and seeing what that looks like.

Comment: It just prints the value as a string (with non-ascii chars as octal of course). Printing the type shows it's a `gdb.Value`. Perhaps this has changed?

Comment: It's quite possible that either the type or the definition of `startingAddress` has changed.

Comment: Based on [this doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Values-From-Inferior.html), maybe try replacing `startingAddress` with `startingAddress.bytes`?

Comment: `'gdb.Value' object has no attribute 'bytes'` :(

Comment: Can you `dir(startingAddress)` and see what attributes it *does* have?

Answer (score 13):

You might use the `x` command to dump the memory your `char`-pointer points to:

```
(gdb) x/32xb buf
```

shows the first 32 bytes.

See

```
(gdb) help x
```

for details.

Comment: I am doing some asm debugging and trying to maximize readability by making it easy to read hex and ascii independently when they are side by side in a string.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who shares the irritation with octal escape-sequences in GDB, it's easy to fix (if you're prepared to build GDB yourself): in gdb/valprint.c, find the comment:

```
/* If the value fits in 3 octal digits, print it that
                     way.  Otherwise, print it as a hex escape.  */
```

and comment out the following 4 lines - all escape-sequences will then be printed as hex.

Answer (score 3):

A small variation of the OP's answer, for the use-case of 8-bit arrays that don't necessarily terminate at the first occurrence of `\0`, and which tries to also respect the `print elements` and `print repeats` parameters of GDB:

```py
    from __future__ import print_function
    
    def print_extended_ascii_char(charCode):
      if charCode == ord('"'): return r'\"'
      if charCode == ord('\\'): return r'\\'
      if 32 <= charCode <= 126: return "%c" % charCode
      return r"\x%02x" % charCode
    
    class PrettyPrintString(gdb.Command):
        """Command to print an array of 8-bit bytes, using ASCII when possible and hex otherwise.
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469844/4958"""
    
        def __init__(self):
            # care for old GDB (< 8)
            try: GDB_COMPLETE_EXPR = gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION
            except: GDB_COMPLETE_EXPR = gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL
            super (PrettyPrintString, self).__init__(name="ascii-print",
                    command_class=gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                    completer_class=GDB_COMPLETE_EXPR, prefix=True)
    
        def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
            if not arg.strip():
                print("What do you want me to print?")
                return
            # Limit on string chars or array elements to print
            limit = gdb.parameter('print elements')   or 10000000000
            # Threshold for repeated print elements 
            repeats = gdb.parameter('print repeats')  or 1000000
            start = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg)
            p = 0
            print('"', end='')
            i = 0
            unprinted = (None, 0)
            while i < start.type.sizeof:
                i += 1
                charCode = int(start[p])
                toPrint = print_extended_ascii_char(charCode)
                if toPrint == unprinted[0]:
                  unprinted = (toPrint, unprinted[1] + 1)
                else:
                  if unprinted[0] is not None:
                    print(unprinted[0] * min(unprinted[1], limit - (i - unprinted[1])), end='')
                    if i > limit:
                      print('...', end='')
                      break
                  unprinted = (toPrint, 1)
                p += 1
            if i - unprinted[1] > limit or unprinted[0] is None:
              print('"')
            elif repeats == 'unlimited' or unprinted[1] < repeats:
              print(unprinted[0] * unprinted[1], end='')
              print('"')
            else:
              print('",')
              print("'%s' <repeats %d times>" % (unprinted[0], unprinted[1] - 1))
    
    PrettyPrintString()
```

As before, put the above in some file (say `~/.gdb-AsciiPrint.py`), and either run `source ~/.gdb-AsciiPrint.py` or put that statement in the `.gdbinit` file.
Result/comparison:

```
(gdb) p tokmem[3]
$1 = "\000\030\000-1\320\a\200\031:\200\032[\200\024]\200\033\200\023;\200\034:\200\032[\200\023]\200\033\200\024;\320\r\200$:\200\030;\320\020\200 k\030\060\200!255\200\"\200\r\200\060(k:3,': \"');l\030k;\200+(\250\061)\200,\200\r\200\060(\200\034[\200\062],\200\034[\200\062]);\200+k<\f100\200,l\030k+\f100\200.\200+k<\f200\200,l\030k-\f100\200.\200\r\200*(k\200\063\061\066);\200\060(\200\034[l]);\200*(k\200\064\061\066);\200\020(\200$);\200\017;\200$\030\200$+2;\200\017;\200+l=\200\065\200,\200\060(\200\034[l],\200\034[l])\200.\200\060(\200\034[l]);\200\020(\200$);\200&('\"');\200\017", '\000' <repeats 65285 times>
(gdb) ascii-print tokmem[3]
"\x00\x18\x00-1\xd0\x07\x80\x19:\x80\x1a[\x80\x14]\x80\x1b\x80\x13;\x80\x1c:\x80\x1a[\x80\x13]\x80\x1b\x80\x14;\xd0\x0d\x80$:\x80\x18;\xd0\x10\x80 k\x180\x80!255\x80\"\x80\x0d\x800(k:3,': \"');l\x18k;\x80+(\xa81)\x80,\x80\x0d\x800(\x80\x1c[\x802],\x80\x1c[\x802]);\x80+k<\x0c100\x80,l\x18k+\x0c100\x80.\x80+k<\x0c200\x80,l\x18k-\x0c100\x80.\x80\x0d\x80*(k\x80316);\x800(\x80\x1c[l]);\x80*(k\x80416);\x80\x10(\x80$);\x80\x0f;\x80$\x18\x80$+2;\x80\x0f;\x80+l=\x805\x80,\x800(\x80\x1c[l],\x80\x1c[l])\x80.\x800(\x80\x1c[l]);\x80\x10(\x80$);\x80&('\"');\x80\x0f",
'\x00' <repeats 65285 times>
```

This is slightly hacky, so hopefully the feature will get added to GDB itself.

(Aside: A while ago I asked [a similar question for Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/showing-bytes-as-hexadecimal-escapes-rather-than-octal-escapes), and one of the people who saw the question submitted [a patch to Emacs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27122). It does seem that octal is less popular these days than it used to be; e.g. JavaScript has [deprecated octal](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) escape sequences for its string literals.)

Comment: That answer would be nearly perfect - I've taken the freedom to edit it for directly resolving the `gdb.parameter` and to have a fallback for GDB < 8 where `gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION` does not exist (you may want to see the edit).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your reason to show non-ascii chars in a string a slightly different approach could be to print the string using a different encoding.

In my case I wanted to see the hex values to ensure the string was encoded using ISO8859-1 in a UTF-8 environment. Although [GDB has encoding](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Character-Sets.html), it is not intended, or useable, for this purpose.

While exploring the gdb commands created by the OP and [ShreevatsaR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469844/204658) I discovered the [`Value.string()` function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html) that prints a GDB value as a string if it's a string. You can give it an encoding option so the following Python code adds an `isostring` command to GDB:

```python
from __future__ import print_function

class PrettyPrintString(gdb.Command):
    """Command to print an array of 8-bit bytes as ISO8859-1"""

    def __init__(self):
        super (PrettyPrintString, self).__init__(name="isostring",
                command_class=gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                completer_class=gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION, prefix=True)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        if not arg.strip():
            print("What do you want me to print?")
            return
        value = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg)
        print('"' + value.string("iso8859-1")+ '"')

PrettyPrintString()
```