# GDB print all values in char array

Tags: c, gdb

I am storing various filenames in my array which are partitioned by null bytes. When debugging, I am only able to see the first filename. So, for instance if my array is like this: `hello.txt00000hello2.txt`, I am only able to see `hello.txt`. How can I print the entire array? I have trouble finding such command elsewhere.

Comment: In your example the string is partitioned by a series of `0`s, which is not the same as a null byte. Or is that just for illustration purposes?

Comment: Also, there are many ways of debugging. How is it you print your array?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Its just an illustration. I used memset to set them all to value 0.

Comment: @Brean I just use print

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `x/999bc`, where `999` is the size of your array, for instance:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ gdb ./str
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/paul/src/sandbox/str...done.
(gdb) list
1   int main(void) {
2       char * p = "hello\0world\0hahaha";
3       return 0;
4   }
5   
(gdb) b 3
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004b8: file str.c, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/paul/src/sandbox/str 

Breakpoint 1, main () at str.c:3
3       return 0;
(gdb) print p
$1 = 0x40056c "hello"
(gdb) x/19bc p
0x40056c:   104 'h' 101 'e' 108 'l' 108 'l' 111 'o' 0 '\000'    119 'w' 111 'o'
0x400574:   114 'r' 108 'l' 100 'd' 0 '\000'    104 'h' 97 'a'  104 'h' 97 'a'
0x40057c:   104 'h' 97 'a'  0 '\000'
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 32):

With gdb, you can achieve to print the elements of your array using the following command:

```
(gdb) print *array@size
```

If my variable **array** is a type `char*[]` such as below

```
const char *array[] = {"first","second","third"};
```

Then I could display the 2 first `char*` entries of my array by using:

```
(gdb) print *array@2
$2 = { 0x..... "first", 0x..... "second"}
```

Using it in order to display the arguments of a program is very handy:

```
(gdb) print *argv@argc
```

It's also possible to do the same with **x** commands using `x/Ns *argv`, where *N* is the integer value of *argc* (i.e. for argc = 2, x/2s *argv)

The documentation for the whole magic of the print command is [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html#Arrays).

Comment: This answer is fantastic. I would like to add a variant in case you want an offset:
`array[1]@2` would print `array[1]` and `array[2]`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed-length array and want to see all the data in there - just ask to print the array and you will get the full output, because GDB knows about the size.
If you have a pointer to a fixed-length array then GDB assumes the most common case - a C string, so it stops the display at the first hex null. To see more: de-reference and cast the result as char array with the intended length you want to see.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
static char myarr[55] = "hello.txt\x00\x00\x00\x000hello2.txt";

int main () {
   char *p = myarr;
   puts (p);
   return 0;
}
```

compiled and run as `gcc -g test.c && gdb -q -ex start ./a.out`:

```
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400535: file test.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:5
5          char *p = myarr;
(gdb) step
6          puts (p);
(gdb) print p
$1 = 0x601060 <myarr> "hello.txt"
(gdb) print *p
$2 = 104 'h'
(gdb) print (char[20])*p
$3 = "hello.txt\000\000\000\000hello2."
(gdb) print (char[55])*p
$4 = "hello.txt\000\000\000\000hello2.txt", '\000' <repeats 31 times>
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /tmp/a.out, process 456
hello.txt
(gdb) quit
```

If you want that to print the sequences in hex instead of in octal - have a look at [54469844](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469844/5027456).

Comment: does that work with dynamic size? `print (char[$eax])*($rbx)` is a syntax error. there seems to be no eval in gdb... currently i use `p/x *($rbx)@$eax` but thats verbose

Comment: You can at least use python commands and do this multi-step (evaluating both expressions), possibly there's even an option to just read the value "differently" - but with plain `print` that's not possible (the `p/x` does work).
The `print ... @` may also work - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545366.

Answer (score 1):

you might try defining the array as:

```
char ** array;

array = malloc( NUM_ROWS*sizeof char* );
for( int i =0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++ )
{
    *array[i] = malloc( NUM_COLUMNS )
}
```

then the code can

```
memset( array[x], '\0', NUM_COLUMNS );
strncpy(array[x], myString, NUM_COLUMNS-1);
```

where myString is the data to place in that row
and

```
for( int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++ )
{
    if( array[i] )
    { // only enters this code block if something placed in row
        printf( "%s\n", array[x] );
    }
}
```

then use 'p array[x]' for each row in the array

Comment: of course, the code also needs to check the returned value of each malloc to assure the operation was successful and at the end of the code pass each row address to free then pass the array to free

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it could be:

```
x/10bs  array@10 

x/10bc  array@10
```

- I debugged corefile and got "Cannot access memory at address" for any other options