# Why does GDB display char in octal?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I don't understand the design choice to represent a char or unsigned char with octal in gdb debug view in vscode as a replacement for an ascii character (if the data in the char is in the range of an ascii character, it shows an ascii character). I'm on ubuntu 17.10 with the latest version of vscode. It's confusing to me, a human, but I'm hopeful that someone can explain the logic behind it. Also, I would like to change this behavior if it is possible.
[image]

Comment: I'm sure that parts of gdb's innards date back decades, when usage of octal notation was quite common, especially when referring to control characters. Here, this character is an unprintable character. It needs to be displayed in some meaningful manner, and, gdb's legacy means that some decades ago a decision was made, for some reason, to use octal. That's all she wrote.

Comment: That makes sense. As I'm working with raw bytes, it would make it so much easier if it was in decimal or hexadecimal!

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to rebuild GDB from source-code (which isn't difficult on Linux!), try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450772/12978961